# Google Calendar API - Service Account - Impersonate User

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, impersonation, service-accounts

I have some difficulty to make work impersonate user with service account on Google Calendar API.
For give service account right on calendar, i created calendar with SA account  for give it the full access rights.
I'm trying to add an event with any user of domain.

I'm setting to $client with impersonate user :

```
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=JSON_CREDENTIAL_SA_FILE);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->authorize();
$client->addScope([Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR]);
$client->setSubject(EMAIL USER TO IMPERSONATE);
```

But when i'm trying to add an events

```
$event = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Event($EventObj);
$event = $service->events->insert($AgendaID, $event);
```

GG Api return is "*A service error occurred | reason:NotFound*", it seems that user used can't found SA calendar ID.

Calendar ID ids not share with user used.

In Google Cloud Plateform, i created the service account and add delegation domain checkbox.

On IAM panel, email of service account is Owner. I gave to user used in my project role *Service Account Token Creator* or *owner* to try but same issue like describe [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHdQ13HSCq8)

On Google Admin, I gave to ID Service Account Scope needed in *Security => API Command* => https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

I was thinking that when using *setSubject*, it's like using SA but like a user.

Insert work if i comment *$client->setSubject(EMAIL USER TO IMPERSONATE);*

I really don't understand why can't used any user of domain to write on SA Calendar.
Did i miss a configuration on google cloud plateform or google admin ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 404 - Not found... it means that the api request work but the calendar is not available for the user. If you want to create an event on the service account calendar with a user, the user must have access to the calendar, i.e., share the service account calendar with the user. Otherwise, DO NOT impersonate any user and you should be good.

Comment: You right Morfinismo, thanks, by sharing calendar id with user, it's working, but I was thinking that when using impersonate with setSubject, it's like using SA but like a user, in other word, you connected with Service Account Email but using User email instead, so if the calendar owner was Service Account, so users can access it without shared it to him.
Did I miss something with understanding Service Account ?
Because if i shared calendar with user, adding user in IAM Service Account with Role *Service Account Token Creator* or just remove user is the same, user can add event in calendar

Comment: 1) Is the user part of Google Workplace or Identity Platform? If not, a service account cannot impersonate the user. 2) If yes, Is the service account set up for Domain Wide Delegation?

Comment: Hi John, as I said, 
*In Google Cloud Plateform, I created the service account and added delegation domain checkbox* and gave scopes in *Google Admin -> Security*, and scope is *Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR*, so all calendar access I think.
Service created in Project, child of domain, same domain for user used.

Yes, the user used is part of Google Workplace.